# Populating a datagrid asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

This is my first `ASP.Net` project. I am used to `WPF`. I am creating this project in `Visual Studio 2010`, using the `C#` language.
I can't find the answer to the following question.

I have a `DataGrid` that needs to show all the inquiries given to that department, which is not on site. So the department needs the `.Net` app to get hold of the `SQL Server 2008 DB`. This is the code I have:
PS : I am used to loading the `SQL` statement into a `DataTable`, but it seems `.Net` doesn't have it.

So what I am asking is, how do I get this method to show into the `DataGrid`, seeing as I can't use the `DataTable` class?

: code :

```
SqlCommand _nuecommand = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter _nuweadapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

try  

{
    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed || 
        conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Broken)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        string _sql = "";
        _nuecommand.Connection = conn;
        _sql = 
            "SELECT [Field],[Field],Field,[Field],[VeField],FieldFROM [Table]" + 
                " WHERE [Field] = 'value' AND [Field] = 'Value' AND" + 
                " [Field] IS NULL ";
        _nuecommand.CommandText = _sql;
        _nuweadapter.SelectCommand = _nuecommand;
        _nuecommand.CommandTimeout = 6000;
        _nuweadapter.Fill(_dtnuwe);
        dgnavrae.DataSource = _dtnuwe.DefaultView;
        dgnavrae.databind();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    LogInInde.Pages.ErrorPage._error = ex.Message;
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Please also remember to dispose of `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataAdapter`, and `SqlConnection`.  They are all `IDisposable`s that will leak resources if not disposed after use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just bind data with grid view like this

```
dgnavrae.DataSource = _dtnuwe.DefaultView;
dgnavrae.DataBind();
```

You need to user `DataBind` method to bind view data with gridview that will do work for you

Comment: _okay that i understand? but after dgnavrae.DataSource = ? i dont know what to put in there? because the _dtnuwe is a datatable name, so i leave out dgnavrae.DataSource = _dtnuwe.DefaultView; and just put in dgnavrae.DataBind();?   yes i am a junior with this  _

Comment: so i just need to put in dgnavrae.databind()

Answer (score 0):

1. The .Net SQL connection using SQL Server 2008 I recommend you create a custom functions class that contains all the code you need to connect to your database and returns the DataTables.
2. I agree with @Pranay Rana, you have to use the `DataBind()` function to "bind" the `DataGrid` with your `DataTable`.
3. If you want to customize your view, you can use the OnRowDataBound event :

   protected void yourDataGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
   {
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
      //your code...
     }
    }

PS: not sure about the "DataGridCommandEventArgs "

Answer (score 0):

`GridView` needs `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `true`

Comment: _I fgured that_ haha nothing showed until i saw this post! thnx, yes i was not allowed to set question to answer as i do not have enough rep, have to wait a few hours ! butim gonna do now, thnx for al

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me! hope this helps other aswell as it did for me :) peace!

```
SqlCommand _nuecommand = new SqlCommand(); 
SqlDataAdapter _nuweadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(); 
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(); 

try   
{ 
    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed ||  
        conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Broken) 
        { 
            conn.Open(); 
        } 

        string _sql = ""; 
        _nuecommand.Connection = conn; 
        _sql =  
            "SELECT [Field],[Field],Field,[Field],[VeField],FieldFROM [Table]" +  
                " WHERE [Field] = 'value' AND [Field] = 'Value' AND" +  
                " [Field] IS NULL "; 
        _nuecommand.CommandText = _sql; 
        _nuweadapter.SelectCommand = _nuecommand; 
        _nuecommand.CommandTimeout = 6000; 
        _nuweadapter.Fill(_dtnuwe); 
        dgnavrae.DataSource = _dtnuwe.DefaultView; 
        dgnavrae.databind(); 

} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
    LogInInde.Pages.ErrorPage._error = ex.Message; 
    throw ex; 
}
```